# SDL_Init undefined despite being linked

Tags: c++, linker, g++, sdl-2, undefined-reference

I am trying to use SDL2 in my C++ program using g++ to compile at command line (well technically I'm using a make file, but I use g++) However, despite including the SDL header and linking the 32 bit mingw SDL libraries, I still get the following error:

```
C:\Users\BOSSLE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXt5lsd.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined
 reference to `SDL_Init'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Z:\build\PotatoEngine.exe] Error 1
```

I cannot figure out why I am getting this error. Here is my test code file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    std::cout << "Hello world! SDL Test" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my makefile where I compile the code.

```
PROG = Z:\build\PotatoEngine.exe
CC = g++
LIBDIR = "Z:/libs"
INCLUDES = "Z:/include"
LIBS = -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2

$(PROG) :
    $(CC) -o $(PROG) -I$(INCLUDES) -L$(LIBDIR) $(LIBS) Z:/code/*.cpp
```

I've been working on this issue for a few days now and I cannot figure it out. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try running `sdl2-config --cflags` and `sdl2-config --libs` to ensure that your flags and libs are accurate. Better yet, use them directly in the makefile: `LIBS = \`sdl2-config --libs\` FLAGS = \`sdl2-config --cflags\` $(CC) -o $(PROG) $(LIBS) $(FLAGS) ...`

Comment: Try putting $(LIBS) **after** Z:/code/*.cpp

Comment: so I've followed both of your suggestions @LambdaBeta and @immibis but I still get errors, it says `/bin/sh: sdl-config: command not found` twice and then it says the same undefined reference to the SDL_Init, and now also an undefined reference to WinMain

Comment: @BossLetsPlays it says `sdl2-config`, but anyway it is unlikely to be present on windows machine. Just do what immibis said (and *only* that), libraries have to come after objects referencing them.

Comment: @keltar oh okay thanks a bunch, that fixed the issue :)